# Phonegap: GCM Push Notification registration call returns OK but device is not even connected to the internet

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have followed [this tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/) and I have the following code:

onDeviceReady I execute:

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"824841663931","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
```

The Handlers:

```
// result contains any message sent from the plugin call
successHandler: function(result) {
    alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
},

errorHandler:function(error) {
    alert(error);
},

onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                    alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
                    localStorage.regid = e.regid
                }
            break;

            case 'message':
              // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
              alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
            break;

            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break;

            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
              break;
        }
    }
```

This code works perfectly if my device is connected to the internet on the first time I open the app.

If my device is not connected the successHandler is being called with "OK" and the onNotificationGCM is never called. Is this normal?

I was expecting that the registration should fail and call the errorHandler or the onNotificationGCM with e.event = 'error' so I would be able to postpone the registration, but this is not happening.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: got the same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **register**

   When you call `pushNotification.register()`:

   - `successHandler` is called if there is no error in parsing your `ecb` and `senderID`. Your `senderID` and application are registered with [GCMRegistrar](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/PushPlugin.java#L65).
   - `errorHandler` is called only if there is a JSON error while parsing the `ecb` or `senderID`

   Once your setup is correct, your `errorHandler` will probably never be called.

   From the [docs](http://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), you have to call the `register` method every time you start the application. This will not create duplicate registrations. The plugin will manage all that itself.
2. **onNotificationGCM**

   Only called when:

   - You receive a notification from GCM.
   - Your application is successfully registered with `GCMRegistrar`
3. **GCMRegistrar**

   - Returns registration ID (for your application and `senderID`) if already registered.
   - If not, it registers your application and `senderID` and then returns registration ID. This requires an Internet connection (AFAIK)

   So when you call `pushNotification.register` the first time, if you are not connected to the Internet, PushPlugin returns `OK` but GCMRegistrar has no registration ID to return to you.